# Java List Collections: Why does get(new Integer(i)) work and not when I declare an integer object first and then pass it through

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, integer

I'm having trouble wording the question, so hopefully the example helps. I am trying to figure out why within the List collection in Java, where the method get() is overloaded by get(O Object) and get(int index), that one of these snippets work and the other doesn't.

*edit: some context for the code, I'm trying to come up with an alternative way to check hits/miss on a LRU cache. ListB is a list containing data values, and listA is the cache of arbitrary length. I'm trying to figure out how come the first snippet works when coming across an int from listB that is contained within the cache (listA)  which in turn removes, and then adds the element to bring it to the front of the list.*

If I declare an Integer object and pass it through the get method it does not work. But if I declare a new Integer object within the get method, it does. For example:

**This works** *This snippet will remove the first occurrence of Integer i it comes accorss*

```
List<Integer> ListA= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i: ListB){
            if(ListA.contains(i)){
                 ListA.remove(new Integer(i));
}}
```

**This does not work** *even though an Integer object is being passed through, this does not work*

```
List<Integer> ListA= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < ListB.size(); i++){ 
            Integer obj = new Integer(ListB.get(i));
            if(ListA.contains(obj)){ //or list.contains(i), neither work
                 ListA.remove(obj); //Does not work
}}
```

Comment: What is the full definition of ListA/B? ie. what elements are in each list and how do they get there? I put a speculative answer on the question, but having the context will help my answer as well as others.

Comment: 1) ListA.contains(obj) not working because you are creating a new object
2) ListA.get(i) is not working because i is just an index for loop like 0,1,2...ListB.size()

Answer (score -1):

You shoudn't be creating a new Integer instance when retreive it from the list:

```
List<Integer> ListA= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < ListB.size(); i++){ 
    Integer obj = ListB.get(i); // Get the object from List B, do not create a new object from a reference in List B
    if(ListA.contains(obj)) {
       ListA.remove(obj);
}}
```

Comment: Don t contains and remove use equals for comparison?